# I'm going to wire 2 batteries together into a circuit but one has 3 wires and the other has 2 wires how can I make this work?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, wiring

I have a battery in a circuit I want to add another battery which is the same voltage and amps but 2 wires can I just connect the positives and negatives and leave the white in the circuit?

Comment: Are you trying to increase the voltage or current (connect in series or parallel)?  Also, providing pictures and/or part numbers of the batteries will help us provide a useful answer.  Whatever you do, do it outside on a fireproof surface.

Comment: Connecting two batteries in parallel, even if they have the same nominal voltage, can be very dangerous. Don't try this until you are absolutely certain that you can do it safely.

Comment: I wanted to extend the capacity or prolong the power output  of said circuit.

Comment: Okay so I did the unthinkable and used my Mcgyver skills and I wired it together it didn't burst into 

Answer (score 0):

So I wanted to increase the power and extend the mAh from 8hours to 12hours I knew that by adding the additional battery would draw power from the other one. So I wouldn't reach the entire 12mAh but I may extend it to around 10mAh. The device was already having problems with the new existing battery with the load circuit. I was always having to unplug the device and then plug it back in. I was hoping that the additional battery would help with the load circuit and I was correct, the device works great and the other battery has corrected the load imbalance. The device takes longer to  charge but it doesn't overheat and I have used it for over 6hours with still over half a charge left

Comment: You posted this as an answer, but it's not an answer. And I'm very confused about what you're saying here, 10-12 mAh is basically nothing, that's less than most button batteries!

Comment: Do you mean Ah?